# tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'content') on Safari html br tag issue

Tags: tinymce

I am trying to insert `<p>Nice Day</p>` into an area using tinyMCE Editor.

When I attempt to copy data at the cursor position, it jumps down a couple lines.  See below:

.cursor

Nice Day

In using 'inspect element' on Safari, there is an html 'br' tag appended at the end of this string. (In this description, brackets around 'br' are interfering with the display, so I left them out.)  This 'br' is what is causing the extra line space to appear.

The browser is Safari.

The line of code I'm using is:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'content');
```

What is causing the 'br' tag to be inserted?
Does anyone have any experience with this kind of issue and/or any suggestions as how to eliminate the html 'br' tag?

Thank you.

Comment: The string "Nice Day" is enclosed in html parargraph tags <p> and </p>.   The brackets did not show up.  Also, the line '.cursor' is meant to denote the current cursor position.

Comment: Oh, to be clear, the precise parameter is: tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'Nice Day');

Comment: Can you create a TinyMCE Fiddle (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/) that shows your exact configuration and this command leading to the incorrect result?   Without running code it will be hard to provide any specific feedback.

Answer (score 0):

As is Safari I would suggest to try with the TinyMCE popup:

```
tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<p>Nice Day</p>');
```

I suppose you know you have to add it in the initialization:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    [...]
    setup: function (editor) {
        tinyMCEPopup.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<p>Nice Day</p>');
    }
});
```